# telegram error node js

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegram

> error: [polling_error] {"code":"ETELEGRAM","message":"ETELEGRAM: 404
> Not Found"}

```
const token = require('./config.json')
const TelegramApi = require('node-telegram-bot-api')

const bot = new TelegramApi(token, {polling:true})


bot.on("message", msg => {
    console.log(msg)
})
```

Comment: Посмотри какое значение в `token` правильный ли..

Comment: @Rudi , понял. по старому опыту с ботами для дса решил попробовать сделать